Can't create a lookup with Fontforge internal scripting
AddLookup( "myAnchor", "gpos_mark2base", 0, " " )
AddLookupSubtable("myAnchor", "myAnchor1")
I run this in execute script windows and got error message "bad type for argument"
enter image description here
What weht wrong???
I expected FF creates a lookup
